# Convert d3.js treemap to image

Tags: python, d3.js, treemap

The original output of d3 treemap is in HTML format. How can I  convert the HTML treemap to image(`.png`, `.jpg`)? Is there any solution in Python?

Why do I need this? Because I wanna share the treemap via social network tools which need an image.

---

Addition: I found `Phantomjs`.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Related-Projects

Comment: Is the output in svg? If so, in Internet Explorer you can right click on the treemap and save as svg. The only problem is that you may lose some of the formatting. I think this happens when some of the formatting is part of your css file rather than encoded directly into the svg.

Once you've got an SVG you should be able to open this in a vector graphics editing package and then export into your chosen format.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes, screenshot of the treemap only.